# How does the function that deletes an element in an array work?

Tags: c

I know that the following function deletes an element from an array.

```
void removeElem (int V[N], int pos, int *length)
{
    int i;
    for (i = pos; i < *length-1; i++)
        V[i] = V[i+1];
    *length = *length - 1; // (*length)--
}
```

But I don´t understand why, because if my list has 4 elements and the position I want to delete is the position number 3, I will never enter in the loop because of this "`3<3`".

Comment: Show how the function is used in a minimal main.

Comment: The loop is not needed when deleting the last element - there are no elements above it to be copied down.  Only the array length needs decrementing.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an array

```
A={10,20,30,40,50}
```

and let n=5 represent the size of the array.

If I want to delete the last element (50, in this case) then I can simply decrease the size of my array (i.e. n=4).

```
 *longi = *longi - 1;
```

`*longi` represents the size of the array which we are decreasing by 1.

We do not have to do any shifting of array elements for deleting the last element. So We do not enter the loop.
But for any element except the last element all element to the right of element to be deleted is shifted by one position to left. And so we enter the loop.